# How to remove and reset collection in for-each loop in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium: 3.141 in Java

Problem: How to reset collection in for-each loop?

```
WebElement columnid = driver.findElement(By.id("id")); 
List<WebElement> getTaskName = columnid.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'card-title')]")); //gets the list of first 20 elements i.e., 1-20
for(Iterator<WebElement> ite = getTaskName.iterator(); ite.hasNext();)
{
    WebElement el = ite.next();
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",el); //scroll-down one element
    ite.remove(); //have added remove and modified for-each loop with collection to iterator. it doesn't throw concurrentmodifiedexception. 
    getTaskName = columnid.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'card-title')]")); //this gets the list of next 20 elements i.e., 2-21
}
```

Expected Result: I want to **reset** **getTaskName** with elements from 2-21 and re-iterate each element.

Actual Result: **getTaskName** always set to 1-20 and re-iterates from 1-20 and exits.

Please let me know if anything is missing or incorrect from above sample code. Thanks.

Comment: Are the elements dynamically added to the DOM if they are scrolled into view? Otherwise I don't get why you get different elements for the in-loop call to `columnid.findElements`.

Comment: if you want to `clear` your `getTaskName` collection inside forEach loop, you will get `ConcurrentModificationException`. Otherwise you need to do it using `iterator`

Comment: @dpr yes, elements are added dynamically added to DOM after scrolling.

Comment: @Vault23 yes and hence I used iterator but see a issue.

Comment: i made use of collections to replace the list, it worked. resetting is ok now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because the first expression in a for statement (`Iterator<WebElement> ite = getTaskName.iterator()`) is only evaluated once: before the first iteration starts.

So `getTaskName = columnid.findElements(...)` does actually reassign `getTaskName` to the new `List`, but your for loop is still iterating over the iterator that you got the first time. That iterator is tied to the `List` instance that it was obtained from, and will not auto-magically switch lists if you re-assign `getTaskName`.

Assuming you want to keep your loop, you'd need to transform it into a while loop and re-assign the iterator itself to a new iterator instance, like this:

```
WebElement columnid = driver.findElement(By.id("id")); 
List<WebElement> getTaskName = columnid.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'card-title')]")); //gets the list of first 20 elements i.e., 1-20
Iterator<WebElement> ite = getTaskName.iterator();
while(ite.hasNext())
{
    WebElement el = ite.next();
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",el); //scroll-down one element
    ite.remove(); //have added remove and modified for-each loop with collection to iterator. it doesn't throw concurrentmodifiedexception. 
    getTaskName = columnid.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'card-title')]")); //this gets the list of next 20 elements i.e., 2-21
    ite = getTaskName.iterator();
}
```

Note that this strikes me as not very clean. Using an iterator to just get the first element seems completely un-necessary. You could do this instead:

```
WebElement columnid = driver.findElement(By.id("id")); 
List<WebElement> getTaskName = columnid.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'card-title')]")); //gets the list of first 20 elements i.e., 1-20
while(!getTaskName.isEmpty())
{
    WebElement el = getTaskName.get(0);
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",el); //scroll-down one element
    getTaskName = columnid.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'card-title')]")); //this gets the list of next 20 elements i.e., 2-21
}
```

Ideally, you should probably tweak your XPath query to just return the first element in the list.

---

As a separate concern, I'm don't think that what you're trying to do is going to work. As far as I remember from my experience with Selenium, removing an element from the `List` returned by `findElements()` does NOT result in that element being removed from the DOM of the page. So querying `columnid.findElements()` with the same XPath query will always return exactly the same list of `WebElement`. So unless some other script on the web page automatically removes the first DOM element in the list when it is scrolled into view, your loop will always be stuck on the first element.

Comment: Thank you for detailed analysis. I will try both ways along with other points and post status here.

Comment: I think both solutions will not really work as desired as, if you reached the end of your list and no new elements are added/removed, you will always get the same elements in the loop. I think @sridattas, you need to keep track of the elements you already visited to exclude them from the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helping, but I once had a similar problem and fixed it with iterating backwards.

The list is filled with numbers 0 - 4.
This does not remove every element of the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size (); i++) {
  arr.remove (i);
}
```

output = [1, 3]

But this works fine:

```
for (int i = arr.size () - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  arr.remove (i);
}
```

output = []